# Module tag pair not working

Tags: add-on-development, module, tags, debugging

I'm trying to create a module tag but it just isn't working, I'm following the Hello World tutorial at Ellis Lab. My module is installed and the MCP part is working. Here is my mod file:

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Facebook_Photos {

    public $return_data = "";

    // Constructor
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->EE =& get_instance();
        $this->return_data = 'Hello World';
        return $this->return_data;
    }

    public function get_photos()
    {
        $this->return_data = 'Hello World';
    }
}

?>
```

Just in case here is my tag pair in my template (it's the only template that exists):

```
{exp:facebook_photos:get_photos}
```

I’m getting the following error from EE:

> The following tag cannot be processed:
>
> {exp:facebook_photos:get_photos}
>
> Please check that the ‘facebook_photos’ module is installed and that ‘get_photos’ is an available method of the module

Comment: Can you restructure your question to include the full module class code? It's really hard to see what's going on. Is `get_photos` in your `Facebook_photos` class? PS I highly doubt it's anything to do with your language file.

Comment: Thanks for the thought - I figured it out and posted the answer below.

Comment: I just reformatted your question to make it more clear what the actual problem was. In the future, try to format your questions so that it’s clear what the issue is, even to people who haven’t been involved in the thread, so that it might help someone else with the same issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The ‘p’ in your module’s class name must be lowercased.

From http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/modules.html#the-core-module-file-mod-module-name-php:

> The Core Module file is used for outputting content via Templates and doing any processing that is required by both the Control Panel and any module tags contained in a template. **It includes a class with a name that matches the package (the first letter of the class name must be capitalized).**

Answer (score 2):

Ok, finally got it - took me forever but now I can hopefully help someone else that runs into this.

I checked that my `mod.facebook_photos.php` had the method `get_photos` and that everything was spelled right and it was. So I thought I'd check if it was installed, it was - but at the same time it wasn't.

If you open `system/expressionengine/libraries/Template.php` and go to line `1224` you find the conditional that is causing the error. There I placed some debugging information:

```
echo 'Class Name: ' . $class_name . '<br/>';
echo 'Tag Data Class: <br/>';
var_dump($this->tag_data[$i]['class']);
echo '<br/>Modules: <br/>';
var_dump($this->modules);
echo '<br/>Module Data Class Name: <br/>';
var_dump($this->module_data[$class_name]);
```

Everything came back as expected except for the last one that threw a PHP error where it couldn't find that index. So I echoed out the `$class_name` and I received `Facebook_photos`. To my surprise on line `1205` you see the following:

```
$class_name = ucfirst($this->tag_data[$i]['class']);
```

So what I did was go to my `upd.facebook_photos.php` and renamed every place that Facebook_Photos to Fbphotos (I removed the underscores to create a shorter namespace). I then renamed all file names and class names to match this new namespace making sure that the class names have the first letter uppercased (as that is what `ucfirst`) does.

Also, my tag pair had to change due to the new namespace - it now looks like this:

```
{exp:fbphotos:get_photos}
```

Now the `get_photos` method works as expected. Hope this helps someone else!

Comment: Maybe it was expecting `Facebook_photos` instead of `Facebook_Photos`? I didn't think PHP class names were case sensitive though. Glad you solved it, thanks for posting the solution!

Comment: I don't think that they are case sensitive, but when they're doing an `in_array` check that's what's throwing the error.

Comment: Brandon Kelly's response above is correct. Case sensitivity is built-in. Not a bug. I just wanted to make sure that was noted.

Comment: Yeah, I was posting my findings at the same time he was posting his response. They basically got published at the same time, sorry for the redundancy.